# Croix De Fer fork replacement

Tags: disc-brake, fork, replacement, gravel, advice

I own a 2019 Croix De Fer 10 and would like to replace its fork since I recently damaged it. I went on [Genesis's website](https://www.genesisbikes.co.uk/bike/croix-de-fer-10) to try and find out exactly what kind of fork it is, I am quite new to bike maintenance and cannot tell by just looking at it. The only thing I managed to surmise it is a unicrown straight steerer...I *think* it's 1 1/8".

I would love if anyone had any suggestion for a replacement fork I could get or if they could help me understand how to look for the right one.

I found this:

https://www.condorcycles.com/collections/forks/products/condor-bivio-disc-fork

but I am not sure it would work.

Does the replacement need to be a straight steerer or can I also use a tapered steerer (maybe with an adaptor)?

What should I look out for? Will my mechanical disc brakes fit on it?

I just don't know what to even look for to go about and find a replacement. I have tried asking my local shops but they are slammed and I am shielding, so I am not sure what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisH might have experience with that bike. As a steel-framed bike with recent components it is slightly unusual.

Comment: @gschenk mine's a Tour de Fer but very similar. I haven't had the fork off myself so can't be any more sure than the OP. When I needed new headset bearings I put it into a shop for a full service at the same time

Comment: BTW that must have been quite a knock to damage the fork. Mine was fine after a crash that bent my front rim and broke several bones

Comment: Did you contact Genesis and ask if they sell new forks under a crash replacement program?

Comment: @Superman.Lopez I did, they don't. They just gave me the measurements I would need for a replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It looks like [at least one company](https://canecreek.com/FAQ/can-run-tapered-fork-1-1-8-head-tube/) makes a headset that will allow you to fit a tapered steerer in some straight 1⅛" head tubes, but pulling the old headset and installing a new one will be an added expense.
- The brake's actuation method doesn't really matter, but you want to find a fork with the right mounting points for your brake. Your existing brakes use a "post mount". The other mounting systems are flat mount and IS mount. You can get adapters to fit a post-mount brake on either of these. The Condor fork you linked to has an IS mount.
- Your current fork is built for a wheel with a regular quick release. Many disk-brake forks today will be built for through axles. The Condor fork you linked to would work in this respect.
- An important factor to consider is the fork's dimensions, especially the rake and the distance from the axle to the top of the crown--if this is different on the replacement fork, your bike will effectively [lean forward or backward a small amount](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rinard/forklengths.htm), changing the handling. You'll need to contact Genesis to ask for the fork-blade length. According to the company's description, the rake (offset) is 50 mm. The Condor fork has a rake of 45 mm, so probably close enough, but that will change the handling slightly. It's conceivable that a fork with different blade length and rake would wind up producing the same [trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_geometry#Trail), which is a better gauge of how it will handle, but that would be a fantastic coincidence.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for the very detailed explanation :). So in theory the Condor fork would work, albeit with some possible handling changes. I had no idea that changing a fork would involve so many variables.

Comment: @Granvanoeli bikes can be like that. So many variables you were never aware of.